# How to merge several single page PDF files in to one PDF document in Android

Tags: android, pdf, merge, pdf-generation

I have single page several PDF files in my SD card. Now I need to programmatically merge those single page PDF files in to one PDF document. I have used [Android PDF Writer](http://coderesearchlabs.com/androidpdfwriter/) library to create those single PDF files. How can I do that?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

The iText library can merge PDF files, and reputedly there is a version of iText that works on Android.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep there is a version called **droidText**. Due to some policy issues I have shifted to **APW**. Otherwise I used it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple PDF Files on Android with with the latest [Apache PdfBox Release](https://pdfbox.apache.org).

Just add this dependency to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.2'
```

And in an async task do this:

```
private File downloadAndCombinePDFs(InputStream streamToPdf1, InputStream streamToPdf2, InputStream streamToPdf3 ) throws IOException {

    PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
    ut.addSource(streamToPdf1);
    ut.addSource(streamToPdf2);
    ut.addSource(streamToPdf3);

    final File file = new File(getContext().getExternalCacheDir(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf");

    final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        ut.setDestinationStream(fileOutputStream);
        ut.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());

    } finally {
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }
    return file;
}
```